# Quick question about solutions of $y'-y+y^8=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have one small question about solving $y'-y+y^8=0$ but I don't know where. Here's what I do:

Let $u(x) = y(x)^{1-8} = y^{-7}$, then $y=u^{- \frac{1}{7}}$

$\frac{du}{dx} = -7 y^{-8} \frac{dy}{dx} = -7 u^{\frac{8}{7}} (u^{-\frac{1}{7}} - u^{-\frac{8}{7}})= -7u+7$

$u=Ce^{-7x}+1, \ \ C>0$

$y=(Ce^{-7x}+1)^{- \frac{1}{7}}$

And here's where I have doubts. Wolfram says that the solutions of this equation are $\frac{?}{\sqrt[7]{C + e^{7x}}}$ Where $? = e^x, \ \sqrt[7]{-1} \cdot e^x, \ (- 1 )^{2/7} e^x, ..., (- 1 )^{6/7} e^x$.

My question is, should I include the $n$-th roots of $1$ in my solutions or is not always necessary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $n$-th roots of $1$ are complex numbers. I do not think your differentiql equation involved complex variables; the DE is likely to assume real numbers only. Then if so, your solution should be in real numbers only as well. That is, $\displaystyle y=(Ce^{-7x}+1)^{-\frac 17}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[7]{Ce^{-7x}+1}}$ should be fine. (Wolframalpha is always including all possible solutions, whether they be in the real plane or the imaginary.)

Comment: So - just to make sure- if there are no imaginary numbers in the equation and it is not specified that $x,y $ are complex, I needn't worry about considering n-th roots of one?

Comment: I'm confident, and I remember my DE professor told my class this. But to be absolutely sure on your part, check with your professor (if you're taking a DE class right now).

Comment: I'll do that. Thanks!